# I am running our of memory because a variable is exceeding 2^32, is there a way to fix this in javascript or a different language that avoids this?

Tags: javascript, memory

EDIT:
The error happens when mod reaches a value greater than 2^32. Is there any way to increase how many bits mod has for memory, or a better war to store them?

I am running out of memory when running the code.

When running with iterations = 33, I get an error:

Mark-sweep 4622.7 (4655.5) -> 4212.1 (4244.9) MB, 2.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.993, current mu = 0.984) allocation failure; scavenge might not succeed

I am not entirely sure what this error means and couldn't find much information online about it, can someone please help me? I am using VSC IDE if that helps.

```
function run(vals, count) {
let total = 0.5;
let { r, coef, cons, mod } = { ...vals };

        const startTime = performance.now();
    
        for (let j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            const newR = [];
            const newCoef = [];
            const newCons = [];
    
            for (let i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                const calculation = (coef[i] * r[i] + cons[i]) % mod;
    
                if (calculation === 0) {
                    if (coef[i] >= mod) {
                        newR.push(r[i], r[i] + mod);
                        newCoef.push(coef[i], coef[i]);
                        newCons.push(cons[i], cons[i]);
                    } else {
                        total += 1 / mod;
                    }
                } else {
                    newR.push(r[i], r[i] + mod);
                    newCoef.push(3 * coef[i], 3 * coef[i]);
                    newCons.push(3 * cons[i] + mod / 2, 3 * cons[i] + mod / 2);
                }
            }
    
            [r, coef, cons] = [newR, newCoef, newCons];
            mod *= 2;
        }
    
        const endTime = performance.now();
        const executionTime = endTime - startTime;
    
        return { total: total * 100, executionTime: executionTime.toFixed(2) };
    }    
    
    const initialVals = {
        r: [1],
        coef: [3],
        cons: [1],
        mod: 2,
    };
    
    const iterations = 32;
    
    const result = run(initialVals, iterations);
    console.log(`Iterations: ${iterations}, Total: ${result.total}%, Execution Time: ${result.executionTime}ms`);
```

Comment: what are you calculating?

Comment: This will sound crazy, but I am trying to show that no matter the input to the 3n+1 problem, it will always decrease.
What I am trying to calculate is what percentage of inputs decrease for a given number of iterations on the function.

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is. Get an error from where? Based on the code you've provided, it seems that it performs `count * values.r.length` number of iterations (in this case `32 * 1`) and you're adding 2 numbers to each of the 3 arrays per iteration of the inner loop, that shouldn't amount to the memory consumption mentioned in the error.

Comment: VSC doesn't give me any more helpful information about the error. Two things to note: r.length increases for each iteration of count. And mod also grows exponentially.

Comment: Oh, now I've noticed `[r, coef, cons] = [newR, newCoef, newCons];`. Also, I took a quick look at the problem you're trying to demonstrate, it seems that the result of the previous operation is used as the input for the next one. That being said, you don't need to store anything, you can use recursion.

Comment: Do you think that recursion would be better?

Comment: I used GPT to help rewrite the code using recursion, and now it breaks at iterations = 32

Comment: [This is an example using recursion](https://jsbin.com/peyusozuga/edit?js,console) I'm not sure what you're interested in (number of operations, all the results of the calculations or the execution time). This example returns the number of operations it took to get to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You could cache seen values and omit further calculations.

```js
function collatz(v, s = new Set) {
    if (s.has(v)) return [...s];
    s.add(v);
    return collatz(v % 2
        ? v * 3 + 1
        : v / 2
    , s);
}

console.log(collatz(33));
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use the JavaScript BigInt or use a different language like python.